# Implementing inner operator for derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

Assume I have a general Matrix class, for which I have already implemented the operator * which performs the usual matrix multiplication.

Such an operator has the following signature :

```
Matrix operator*(const Matrix & ) const;
```

I now wish to implement another * operator for an inherited class Matrix3 that represents 3x3 matrices.

It would have the following signature :

```
Matrix3 operator*(const Matrix3 &) const;
```

I am looking for the proper way of implementing this operator in order to re-use the code already written for the base class, and to minimize cost (i.e. copying).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work just fine:

```
// Either return base class
Matrix operator*(const Matrix3& other) const
{
    return Matrix::operator*(other);
}

// Or construct from a Matrix
Matrix3 operator*(const Matrix3& other) const
{
    return Matrix3(Matrix::operator*(other));
}

// Either construct the Matrix data in the Matrix3
Matrix3(const Matrix& other)
{
    // Initialize Matrix specifics
    // Initialize Matrix3 specifics
}

// Or pass the Matrix to it's base class so it can take care of the copy
Matrix3(const Matrix& other) : Matrix(other)
{
    // Initialize Matrix3 specifics
}
```

Comment: Good point, if it was me I'd have the Matrix3 class to be able to be constructed from a Matrix class, I'll adjust the code a bit because I just wrote that without having access to an IDE atm.